# Mysql in Xampp is unable to start

Tags: wordpress

When I start mysql in xampp I face above error : Attempting to start MySQL app...

19:46:08  [mysql]     Status change detected: running

19:46:10  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped

19:46:10  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

19:46:10  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,

19:46:10  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

19:46:10  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

19:46:10  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

19:46:10  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this

19:46:10  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums

I have tried above ways:

I have changed the port number in my MySQL config as well as my current working project's wp-config file.

However, in the MySQL config, I am unable to save it, and an error occurs, saying "Cannot create 'E:\xampp\xampp-control.ini'. Access is denied." Why does this happen?

Another approach I tried is as follows:

- Go to the XAMPP folder -> MySQL.

- In the MySQL folder, rename the 'data' folder to 'data_old.'

- Create a new 'data' folder.

- Copy all files from the backup folder and paste them into the newly created 'data' folder.

- Copy the 'mysql' and 'created' databases from 'data_old' and paste them into the 'data' folder.

After following these steps, MySQL starts. However, I am not able to log in to my currently working project in WordPress. How can I resolve these MySQL issues so that I can work on my current project again in wordpress?